# Having issues checking time logs within sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime, discord, discord.py

I've made a few posts here on this, I'm comparing the time stamps correctly now, but on my database I'm not noticing the update to xp.

What I would like my program to do is check the timestamp of the time stored in a DB, update it and then update the experience if it's been a minute after the first time stamp

Currently, I'm doing this on 2 lines, I assume I can get it into one, but my other issues with it is that when it updates the DB, it doesn't update the experience and only the xp_time column.

```
        xp_update = (f"UPDATE xpdata SET xp_time = strftime('%s','now') WHERE user_id = {user_id} AND guild_id = {guild_id}")
        cursor.execute(xp_update)
        xp_update = (f"UPDATE xpdata SET xp = xp + {xp_inc} WHERE user_id = {user_id} AND guild_id = {guild_id} AND strftime('%s',xp_time) < strftime('%s','now','-59 seconds');")
        cursor.execute(xp_update)
```

what my database looks like:

[image: only xp_time gets updated when a user sends a message]

Answer (score 0):

To figure this out, I used a different way of updating the users time, instead of

setting the users time to strftime('%s', 'now') I used the datetime function and called the now parameter, which made it format correctly and is now functional.

```
        xp_update = (f"UPDATE xpdata SET xp = {xp_grab} + {xp_inc} WHERE user_id = {user_id} AND guild_id = {guild_id} AND strftime('%s',xp_time) < strftime('%s','now','-59 seconds')")
        cursor.execute(xp_update)

        lvl_end = int(((xp_grab+xp_inc)//42) ** 0.55)

        time_update = (f"UPDATE xpdata SET xp_time = datetime('now') WHERE user_id = {user_id} AND guild_id = {guild_id} AND strftime('%s',xp_time) < strftime('%s','now','-59 seconds')")
```